# Error message: loadNamespace(name): there is no package called ‘yaml’

Tags: r, install.packages

I just started R for the first time in a while and got an error message when importing the xml2 and other packages into R.

```
install.packages("xml2")
library(xml2)
result <- read_xml("IE0216C.xml")
```

That is all I´ve been doing and I get these two messages:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\alex-\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0OcyfG\downloaded_packages
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
> library(xml2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xml2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package named 'Rcpp'
```

I worked with R for quite a while last year and never got this erro, I´d appreciate a lot if someone could help me ou.

best, Alex

Comment: please read the output of `install.packages('yaml')` _very_ carefully -- it's likely it failed to install for some reason and the output will give you a hint as to why

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I installed yaml separately and did not get any error messages but  R tells me that the read_xml function does still not exist.

Comment: repeat this process for `install.packages('xml2')` :)